# C# MongoDB Driver: Querying Array of Authors for partial or complete match on author full name

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm using the MongoDB C# Driver version `2.11.0` to query against a collection of Book documents.

This is what the book model looks like, reduced to include only fields of interest:

```
public class Book
{
    public string Title { get; set;}
    public List<Author> Author { get; set; }
    # bunch of other fields
}

public class Author
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

}
```

Given an author

```
{
    FirstName: "Mary",
    LastName: "Doe
}
```

I'm trying to write a query that will return all matches whether the author search criteria is `Mary`, `Doe`, or `Mary Doe`.

I have something like this:

```
var searchValue = "Mary Doe";
var regex  = new Regex(searchValue, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

var results = booksCollection.AsQueryable<Book>()
              .Where(book =>
                 book.Author.Any(author =>
                   regex.isMatch(author.FirstName) ||
                   regex.isMatch(author.LastName)
                 )
              );
```

which works when searching for `Mary` or `Doe`, but not `Mary Doe`.
How can I get this to work? I have tried adding

```
regex.isMatch($"{author.FirstName} {author.LastName}")
```

as a third condition, but that causes the driver to throw an `InvalidOperationException`.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried to convert your regex into `"(Mary)|(Doe)"`?

Comment: @mickl I hadn't tried that until you suggested it. I was able to put together some logic that replaces spaces in between words of the search criteria string with the regex logical or. It works. Good thinking.

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments you can use the or operator in the regular expression:

```cs
var client = new MongoClient();

var db = client.GetDatabase("test");

var collection = db.GetCollection<Book>("test");
var searchValue = "(Mary)|(Doe)";
var regex = new Regex(searchValue, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

var results = collection.AsQueryable()
    .Where(book =>
        book.Author.Any(author =>
            regex.IsMatch(author.FirstName) ||
            regex.IsMatch(author.LastName)
        )
    ).ToList();

foreach (var result in results.SelectMany(x => x.Author.Select(a => new
{
    x.Title,
    a.FirstName,
    a.LastName
})))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Title: {result.Title}, FirstName: {result.FirstName}, LastName: {result.LastName}");
}
```

If we seed our collection with the following data:

```js
> db.test.insertMany([{
   Title: "Title 1",
   Author: [{ 
      FirstName: "Bob",
      LastName: "Bob"
  }]
},
{
   Title: "Title 2",
   Author: [{ 
      FirstName: "Mary",
      LastName: "Doe"
   }]
},
{
   Title: "Title 3",
   Author: [{ 
      FirstName: "Mary",
      LastName: "Bob"
   }]
},
{
   Title: "Title 4",
   Author: [{ 
      FirstName: "Bob",
      LastName: "Doe"
   }]
},
{
   Title: "Title 5",
   Author: [{ 
      FirstName: "Doe",
      LastName: "Bob"
   }]
},
{
   Title: "Title 5",
   Author: [{ 
      FirstName: "Bob",
      LastName: "Mary"
   }]
}]);
```

The above C# application outputs the following:

```
Title: Title 5, FirstName: Doe, LastName: Bob
Title: Title 4, FirstName: Bob, LastName: Doe
Title: Title 2, FirstName: Mary, LastName: Doe
Title: Title 5, FirstName: Bob, LastName: Mary
Title: Title 3, FirstName: Mary, LastName: Bob
```

However, the above query won't be that perforant on large datasets and even if you add 2 indexes of the following indexes, it won't be able to utilize them due to it being a case insensitive regex and will fall back to a standard collection scan.

```js
db.test.createIndex({"Author.FirstName" : 1});
db.test.createIndex({"Author.LastName" : 1});
```

However, if you change the regex to be case insensitive.

```cs
var regex = new Regex(searchValue);
```

Then this will be able to utilize the 2 indexes created and do 2 index scans, and use index intersection (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-intersection/).

```
IXSCAN { Author.FirstName: 1 }, IXSCAN { Author.LastName: 1 }
```

But this might not be ideal for your application to have case sensitive queries. This is where having a text index might be more ideal. So let's create a text index and update our query for this example

```js
db.test.createIndex(
   {
     "Author.FirstName": "text",
     "Author.LastName": "text"
   }
 )
```

Below is the C# to use the text index that we've created.

```cs
var collection = db.GetCollection<Book>("test");
var searchValue = "Mary Doe";
var filter = Builders<Book>.Filter.Text(searchValue, new TextSearchOptions {CaseSensitive = false});

var results = await collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync();

foreach (var result in results.SelectMany(x => x.Author.Select(a => new
{
    x.Title,
    a.FirstName,
    a.LastName
})))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Title: {result.Title}, FirstName: {result.FirstName}, LastName: {result.LastName}");
}
```

Executing the above will output the same as the regex example.

```
Title: Title 5, FirstName: Doe, LastName: Bob
Title: Title 4, FirstName: Bob, LastName: Doe
Title: Title 2, FirstName: Mary, LastName: Doe
Title: Title 5, FirstName: Bob, LastName: Mary
Title: Title 3, FirstName: Mary, LastName: Bob
```

However, this will utilize the text index and perform a lot better.